# Update-offline Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, offline

I am a newbie on this list.  Thanks for the help.

I am trying to do Update_offline for Ubuntu 20.04

1. Have the apt-offline.sig file on the remote host created.
2. On running command:  (at the connected computer)
   apt-offline get /tmp/apt-offline.sig --bug-reports --threads 5 -d /tmp/Offline-Get/ > /tmp/offline.out    2> /tmp/offline.errors

I get a lot (235) of correct hits "Downloading http:...."

I get too many (105) "ERROR: Giving up on URL...."

I think 105 errors among 340 tries is too many.

Question:
**Can please anyone chip in and let me know if this is expected, or if you see what I possibly doing incorrectly?**

Many thanks in advance.

Marcelo